# currency validation sholdn't allow zero or a number starts with zero

Tags: validation

I have written a regex for currency which shouldn't accept 0 or a number starts with 0

```
/^\$?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{1,2}){0,1}$/
```

But it still accepts 0 and numbers starts with 0.

Answer (score 0):

In general, matching negatives with regular expressions is not the easiest thing to do. One option that would probably make your code more human readable is using multiple regular expressions, e.g., first

```
if (not /^\$0/)
  if (/whatever else you do want it to match/)
    // whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `/^\$?(?:[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})*)(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$/`. Not sure if that's exactly what you need, but the main point is to match `[1-9]` for leading digit.

Edit: doesn't allow `$.99`, but your example doesn't either so not sure if you want that.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering..i will look forward to the suggestion you have given.